# Superset: Change title of CSV download from timestamp-based to instead be name of chart being exported

Tags: csv, export-to-csv, apache-superset

Currently, when exporting a CSV file with Apache Superset, the title of the CSV file is saved as a timestamp-based title.

We've had users ask if we can make the CSV export a chart-based title instead. Is this doable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not currently possible.  It's a good idea though, in my opinion.  You can upvote an existing feature request here: https://github.com/apache/superset/discussions/21859